# Ebay Restful API createshippingfulfillment Bad Request 400 error

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I tried to use PostMan to send a request to eBay's [createShippingFulfillment](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/fulfillment/resources/order/shipping_fulfillment/methods/createShippingFulfillment), and that works.  However, when I tried to post it in VS, I got Bad Request Error.

```
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'
```

Below is detailed error

```
{[
  {
    "errorId": 32200,
    "domain": "API_FULFILLMENT",
    "category": "REQUEST",
    "message": "Invalid line item id: ''"
  }
]}
```

When I checked the value of lineItemId it is correct and also I've use `string` and `long` for `lineItemId` but still the same error.

```
{"lineItems":[{"lineItemId":"100224635xxxxx","quantity":1}],"shippedDate":"2020-01-24T01:25:15.604Z","shippingCarrierCode":"Couriers Please","trackingNumber":"6J7042xxxx"}
```

Codes below:

```
string endpoint = string.Format("sell/fulfillment/v1/order/{0}/shipping_fulfillment", orderFromOrd.StoreOrderId);
Fullfillment fulfillment = new Fullfillment();

            fulfillment.trackingNumber = orderFromOrd.TrackingNo;
            fulfillment.shippingCarrierCode = base.GetCarrierName(_carriers, orderFromOrd);
            fulfillment.shippedDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ");

            foreach (var ol in sentOrigOLOrd)
            {
                var checkIfsentinOrd = checkOLinStore.Where(x => x.lineItemId == ol.StoreOrderLineId).FirstOrDefault();
                if (checkIfsentinOrd != null)//Only not fulfilled orderlines & sent orderlinestatus in Ordmation
                {

                    FulfillmentLineItems line = new FulfillmentLineItems();
                    line.lineItemId = Convert.ToInt64(ol.StoreOrderLineId); // line-item-id from store Order
                    line.quantity = ol.Qty;
                    fulfillment.lineItems.Add(line);
                }
            }

HttpResponseMessage response = _requestHelper.PostHttpResponse(endpoint, fulfillment);

public HttpResponseMessage PostHttpResponse(string requestUri, object data)
        {
            // Serialize our concrete class into a JSON String
            var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            // Wrap our JSON inside a StringContent which then can be used by the HttpClient class
            var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using (var client = CreateHttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestUri, httpContent).Result;
                    //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return response;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GetErrorsResponse(response);
                        throw new HttpRequestException(string.Format("There was an exception trying to post a request. response: {0}", response.ReasonPhrase));
                    }
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                    //return null;
                }
            }
        }

private HttpClient CreateHttpClient()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            string baseAddress = WebApiBaseAddress;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseAddress))
            {
                throw new HttpRequestException("There is no base address specified in the configuration file.");
            }
            client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 59);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", _cred.eBayToken));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("LegacyUse", "true");
            return client;
        }
```

Comment: It works in PostMan, doesn't work in c#.  We need to see the code that doesn't work if we're to help you.  Show us how you're performing the query in c#.

Comment: I will edit the question to add the codes.

Comment: Thanks.  A bad request suggests you are not sending the exact correct structure, implying the JSON in your question isn't what you are producing with C#.  Can you also include how `PostHttpResponse(..., object data)` is called?  Specifically, how the `data` parameter is created?  The structure of your JSON payload will be directly tied to how that object was made.

Comment: Already edited the question

Comment: How about if you try `httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");` after `var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`?

Comment: it doesn't make any difference. Same error. Do you have an idea why the error showing invalid line item id?